# Wicket: component.onBeforeRender vs. behavior.onBeforeRender

Tags: wicket

recently i needed to determine the visibility of a component depending on the visibilty of the respective child components (container should be visible if at least one child is visible). 
Due to the fact i'm setting the visibility of every component in the respective onConfigure()-methods i cant use this method to fullfil my needs. So i switched into the onBeforeRender-methods and did the job there -> works great. 
After that i wanted to extract this into a behavior since this is more reusable. Still i cant use the onconfigure-method and i tried the respective beforeRender-method. But now wicket throws an exception claiming

"Cannot modify component hierarchy after render phase has started (page version cant 
change then anymore)"

I think either the naming or the behavior of this method is weird. Is there no possibility to solve this with a behavior? :(

What do u think?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably override the container's `isVisible()` method to call the `isVisible()` method of all its children (or at least until one of them returns true).

I prefer overriding `isVisible()` in general unless visibility depends on outside factors (i.e. anything other than the component's model or its children). It's much more readable this way. Obviously what you have to watch out for if you do this is to never call expensive operations in your `isVisible()` implementation.

Comment: Well, overriding isVisible() might be a solution. But still, i'd rather implement the logic inside a behavior since this is more reusable.

Comment: I don't know, creating an abstract `OnlyVisibleIfChildIsVisibleContainer` component sounds pretty reusable to me.

Comment: Well the problem is, im bound to this container in this case. I cant append the respective behavior to i.e. an ListView or Border or any other component. The logic would be "bound" in the hierarchy and inside this very container.

Comment: You can't attache the behavior to a ListView, but you could put the ListView in a custom container (e.g. ShyContainer).  Such a container could be provided references to certain components to check for visibility.

Comment: A behavior can't manipulate the visibilty setting of a Component during the onBeforeRender() call.
This is because the component has already determined that it will be visible (and will continue with it's rendering routine no matter what you do to the visible flag)

So if you want to do it with a Behavior you should:
- Override the Behavior.onConfigure() Method
- Check if its a MarkupContainer (?), iterate over the children, call "configure()" on them and check if they are visible

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `EnclosureContainer` which implements exactly what you ask, but for a single child. It should be easy to extend to multiple children.

The trick is to call the children's `onConfigure` method in the container's `isVisible()`:

```
public boolean isVisible()
{
    child.configure();
    return child.determineVisibility();
}
```

From `Component#onConfigure()`:

```
     * EG to link visiliby of
     * two markup containers the following should be done:
     * 
     * 
     * final WebMarkupContainer source=new WebMarkupContainer("a") {
     *  protected void onConfigure() {
     *    setVisible(Math.rand()>0.5f);
     *  }
     * };
     * 
     * WebMarkupContainer linked=new WebMarkupContainer("b") {
     *  protected void onConfigure() {
     *      source.configure(); // make sure source is configured
     *      setVisible(source.isVisible());
     *  }
     * }
```

This is based on Wicket 1.5